# GitHub source code embedded in my HTML page?

Tags: html, github

I would like to display a code snippet from my own public GitHub source repo in my own web site, without having to make a copy. This is for a tutorial to illustrate some programming concepts. So not to run it but to pretty print it, as it were.

I bet this is something that many people need. I am looking for a lead on how to do this.

Comment: I don't think the "moderators" read the question. In what way is it unfocused, or ask more than one question. Com'on guys don't add to the well known unfriendliness of SO.

Comment: @pitosalas You can use `gist.github.com`. But frankly your question is not regarding the code. But you are asking help to provide you code for your requirement. Hence the community will not allow this as it is not what this community does. It will help you in your queries and not provide free codes. Please make sure that the moderators are extremely good and helpful and they read your question very carefully. We are very friendly here. And do not want to encourage something that will not support the rules of the SO community.

Comment: @jaffer thanks but. I’ve used SO for a long time. I’m aware of the dynamics and reputation. But at least you tried to give me a reason...so thanks. But the reason is not that the question is unfocused, nor that I am asking you to write my code, it’s because, maybe, I am asking for a pointer to a tool or recommended library, which technically is not permitted although as you know it happens all the time. But thanks for taking the time to give a reasoned answer.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words Pitosalas. But the query you have asked generates a thought regarding the library or asking for free code. Thank you for your clarification. But really it creates a thought similar to what I have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the GitHub API to accomplish this.

See the [`Get Contents` endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents).

Comment: Thanks, but please take a look at my Clarification above. Is that how you understood my question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that either by publishing your repo on npm and then referring it as npm dependency in projects package.json.
or 2nd , you can directly refer GitHub repo as dependency in package.json.

Hope this gets you in right direction.

thanks

Comment: Thanks,  it please double check my clarification above. Is that how you understood the question?